# Finding the largest possible value of a non-defined function?

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am confused, I've never had a similar problem. It seems pretty simple but I have no idea of the approach I should take. Hint me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean value theorem should be the way to approach this problem, since it relates the growth of $f$ to that of its derivative. Recall that the theorem says that if $f$ is continuous and differentiable, then 
 $$ \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(c) $$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$.
In this case, taking $a=2$, $b=0$, we have
 $$ \frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}=\frac{f(2)+3}2=f'(c) $$
for some $c$ between $0$ and $2$. We do not know what $c$ is, but we know that $f'(c)\le 5$, regardless of the value of $c$. This gives us 
 $$ \frac{f(2)+3}2\le 5, $$
or $f(2)\le10-3=7$, so $7$ is the largest value $f$ could take.

To see that this is indeed the answer (instead of a smaller number perhaps obtained by another method), we need an example where $f(2)=7$. Take $f(x)=-3+5x$. Then $f'(x)=5$ for all $x$. Also, $f(0)=-3$, and $f(2)=10-3=7$.

---

Another user posted a solution which unfortunately does not work. Sadly, they deleted it. Since it is a natural approach, and the reason why it fails is subtle, I will indicate here what their approach was: They suggested to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, to get $$ f(2) = f(0) +\int_0^2 f'(x)\,dx, $$
so $f(2)\le f(0)+\int_0^25\,dx=10-3=7$. The problem is that the fundamental theorem does not apply in general to arbitrary derivatives and, in fact, there are derivatives that are not Riemann integrable. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) for an example. This would have been a correct argument if we knew, for example, that $f'$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The largest possible value will be when the function continously increases at a slope of $5$ , if it increases at any less value it wont be maximum , so it should be a straight line from $0$  to $2$ with a slope of 5 ie the value of  $f(2)$ will be $5x-3$ . Put $x = 2$ you will get $7$ .

Comment: I think you mean $f(x) = 5x - 3$, so that $f(2) = 7$.

Comment: ya right , i was in a hurry that is why ;) !

Answer (score 0):

Think, at $x=0$, we know taht $f(0)=-3$. Then as we increase $x$, the function $f$ increases if $f'(x)>0$. If we want $f(2)$ to be as large as possible once we get to $x=2$, we should take $f'(x)$ to be as large as possible the 'whole way to' $x=2$. But the largest $f'(x)$ can be is $5$. So if we let $f'(x)=5$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$, then the total change in the function is 
$$
\Delta x\; f'(x)=(2-0)5=(2)5=10
$$
since we started at $f(0)=-3$, the largest possible value of $f(2)$ is $-3+10=7$.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is achieved when the derivative is at its maximum, that is, $f'(x)=5$. Thus $f(x)=5x+C$. Putting in $f(0) = -3$, we get $C=-3$. Thus $f(2)=7$.

Comment: "The maximum is achieved when the derivative is at its maximum". Yes. Why?